# ngOnChanges not triggered though I called ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges

Tags: angular, ngonchanges, change-detector-ref

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input()
  value: number;

  constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    of(1).subscribe(v => {
        this.value = v;

        console.log(1);

        this.cdr.detectChanges();

        of(2).subscribe(() => {
          console.log(2);
        });
      })
  }

  ngOnChanges(c: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(3);
  }
}
```

I expected the sequences of the console.log should be `1, 3, 2` but it only prints `1, 2`.

I know `ngOnChanges` will be only triggered when only `input` change comes from a template binding.

So I called `this.cdr.detectChanges()` right after `console.log(1)` but it didnt work.

What's the problem here?

I made stackblitz example here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ugdba1

**Extra Question**

If it's not possible to trigger the `ngOnChanges` inside the component, what lifecyle hooks will be triggered on `this.cdr.detectChanges()`?

Comment: If you really want to trigger `ngOnChanges()` you could just call `this.ngOnChanges()`. It isn't elegant, but I'd say trying to manually trigger the hook by any other means also isn't.

Comment: Ok so it's impossible to trigger it automatically..

Comment: I'm not aware of such method.

Comment: can you check my extra question too?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ngOnChanges` is called when an Input Parameter is changed from your parent component.

If you want to do something after any detection you should use `ngAfterViewChecked()`

Comment: but it should be called if I call `detectChanges`?

Comment: No... Only when a parameter Changed

Comment: is there any way that I can trigger the ngOnChanges from my component?

Comment: Wrap the code inside your `ngOnChanges` inside another function and call that function instead of  `this.cdr.detectChanges()`

Comment: my purpose it to trigger the ngOnChanges inside the component, just let me know if it's impossible

Comment: You can call `this.ngOnChanges()` but this is an anti-pattern

Answer (score 1):

`this.cdr.detectChages()` calls change detection on the **current component template**. that means if current component contains `<child [data]="someData"></child>` then its `[data]` input will be checked for changes. `child.ngDoCheck()` will be called and if `someData` is new value `child.ngOnChanges(...)` will be called.

Comment: how to trigger the ngOnChanges then?

Comment: the hook is not meant to be "triggered" by developer. you can just call it if you want it that much just do `this.ngOnChanges({})`